# Let user select a single cell in an NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I'm writing an application with Swift that's using an NSTableView as its main interface. The application presents information from a very large array just like a spreadsheet. How can I let the user select a single cell from the NSTableView?

I've read https://stackoverflow.com/a/20807563/2771733 which states:
`It sounds like you're trying to make a spreadsheet. That's not what a table view is.`
But there's no real solution provided other than "You're best off implementing a custom view" – which seems like a lot of work and is way beyond my current knowledge.

One idea I came across was to disable selecting at all and provide my own mouse handler but I wasn't able to switch off selecting. Even when unchecking all boxes in the Selection section in the Attribute Inspector for the Table View, a user can still select (highlight) a row. And that would interfere with my own mouse handle code.

So, is there any way to (ab)use a NSTableView as a spreadsheet? Or any other hints how I could let a user just select a single cell instead of a whole row?

**Update:** The answer to the [possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50743940/2771733) is just a single sentence recommending NSCollectionView for the task, but does not provide any reasons why. Especially my task to present "information from a very large array just like a spreadsheet" isn't addressed. For example, the NSCollectionViewDataSource protocol enforces you to implement `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:`. But the notion of a (inherently one-dimensional) "number of items" doesn't fit well with the idea of a spreadsheet with its two-dimensional data. The same holds true for `collectionView:itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:` where the index path gives you `the item index within that section`. Again I have to deal with one-dimensional indices for a two-dimensional source.

What I'm looking for is a native solution for rather simple grid views other GUI toolkits provide like FLTK's [Fl_Table](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Table.html) or wxWidget's [wxGrid](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/overview_grid.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get index of currently selected row and column in NSTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722758/how-to-get-index-of-currently-selected-row-and-column-in-nstableview)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I know.

To disable NSTableView row selecting, use either of this two methods in NSTableViewDelegate will work:

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, selectionIndexesForProposedSelection proposedSelectionIndexes: IndexSet) -> IndexSet
optional func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool
```

And to select only a single cell, you can subclass NSTableView and override

```
func validateProposedFirstResponder(_ responder: NSResponder, for event: NSEvent?) -> Bool
```

to determine which view or control in a table need to respond to incoming events. You can read [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/RowSelection/RowSelection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH6-SW9) for more detail about this.

And after your cell is able to handle incoming events, the 'mouse handle code' in your cell you mentioned can be handled.